# Failed prop type, prop is marked as required (but is clearly defined and passed)

Tags: reactjs, undefined, react-props

So I have read a few related questions and have not found a solution that works for me.
Basically I have an autocorrect field (material-ui) that I am trying to pass an options array into, but the options array is passing as undefined even though it is clearly defined in the initial state (and in the console at all times).

This is the error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `options` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(Autocomplete)`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in ForwardRef(Autocomplete) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Autocomplete)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Autocomplete)) (at AddField.jsx:27)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at AddField.jsx:26)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at AddField.jsx:12)
    in div (at AddField.jsx:11)
    in AddField (at App.js:209)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at App.js:208)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at App.js:192)
    in App (at src/index.js:8)
```

The initial state object:

```
state = {
    //more stuff up here cut out due to irrelevance to issue
    addFieldSize: 0,
    addFieldArray: [],
  };
```

The props being passed:

```
<Grid item xs={5}>
            <AddField
              addOptions={this.addFieldArray}
              onChange={this.handleAddFieldChange}
            />
</Grid>
```

and finally the props being received and applied :

```
render(){
const { addOptions, onChange } = this.props;
    return (
          //again some more stuff above that was removed due to irrelevance...
          <Grid item xs={6} className="mb-3">
            <Autocomplete
              className="ml-5"
              id="combo-box-addField"
              onChange={onChange}
              options={addOptions}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.displayValue}
              style={{ width: 300 }}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  required
                  label="Add Field"
                  variant="outlined"
                />
              )}
            />
          </Grid>
//and a little more code below that is also now throwing errors in the console so was excluded...
```

can anyone spot a reason for the options array to be undefined? I am so confused by this as the rest of my autocomplete forms run the exact same way and work perfectly.

Comment: `addFieldArray` is in your state, it's not a class property.

Answer (score 4):

Change `this.addFieldArray` to `this.state.addFieldArray`